# How to solve the ODE: $(x-1)^2y'' -2y = (x-1)^2-\frac{1}{x-1}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the ODE: $(x-1)^2y'' -2y = (x-1)^2-\frac{1}{x-1}$ for $x \ne 1$

I can multiply the equation by $(x-1)$ but I still don't see how that helps. This is clearly not an Euler equation and otherwise I only know to solve such equation with constant coefficients.

What I've tried is guessing that there is a solution of the form of a polynomial, which I can later use to reduce the order. However I am struggling to find such a polynom.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: try to use frobenius method

Comment: Could you elaborate? I haven't learned it yet, so I looked it online, but I am not sure how to use it here

Comment: I actually do not know how to solve this ODE, but I know wolfram alpha can do this. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x-1)%5E2y%27%27+-2+y+%3D+(x-1)%5E2-1%2F(x-1)

Comment: @GabiG it means assume that $y(x) = x^{\alpha} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n(x-1)^n$ and match coefficients ($\alpha$ will be determined by the first term in matching coefficients). This is generally used to solve for the homogenous solution (we have at least one solution of the above form by Fuch's theorem since the ODE has a regular singular point at $x=1$.)

Comment: The homogeneous equation is a Cauchy-Euler equation.

Answer (score 3):

Hint.

Calling $\xi = x-1$

$$
\xi^2y''-2y=\xi^2-\frac{1}{\xi}
$$

This is a linear DE so

$$
y = y_h+y_p
$$

here

$$
y_h = C_1 \xi^2+\frac{C_2}{\xi}
$$

after proposing $y_h =C_0 \xi^{\alpha}$

and

$$
y_p = \frac{3 \left(\xi^3+1\right) \ln (\xi)-\xi^3+1}{9 \xi}
$$

so this way we obtain $y$

NOTE

The particular $y_p$ can be computed with the constant's variation technique (Lagrange) so substituting

$$
y_p = C_1(\xi)\xi^2+\frac{C_2(\xi)}{\xi}
$$

into the particular solution expression, we get

$$
\xi C_2''(\xi)-2C_2'(\xi)+\xi^4C_1''(\xi)+4\xi^3 C_1'(\xi)-\xi^2+\frac{1}{\xi} = 0
$$

Assuming now the independence of $C_1(\xi)$ and $C_2(\xi)$ we can establish

$$
\xi C_2''(\xi)-2C_2'(\xi)= 0\\
\xi^4C_1''(\xi)+4\xi^3 C_1'(\xi)-\xi^2+\frac{1}{\xi} = 0
$$

and after making $Z_1 = C_1', Z_2 = C_2'$ we can proceed with

$$
\xi Z_2'(\xi)-2Z_2(\xi)= 0\\
\xi^4Z_1'(\xi)+4\xi^3 Z_1(\xi)-\xi^2+\frac{1}{\xi} = 0
$$

etc.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x>1$. After change $x-1=e^t$ we get
$$y''-y'-2y=e^{2t}-e^t$$
$$y=y_h+y_p$$
$$y_h=C_1e^{2t}+C_2e^{-t}$$
$$y_p=Ate^{2t}+Bte^{-t}$$
We find $$A=B=\frac13$$
After inverse change $t=\ln(x-1)$ we get final answer for $x>1$
$$y=C_1(x-1)^2+\frac{C_2}{x-1}+\frac13(x-1)^2\ln(x-1)+\frac{\ln(x-1)}{3(x-1)}$$
If $x<1$ we need make change $1-x=e^t$.